# Access property whose name is in another property

Tags: php

I have a class which dynamically wraps all my database tables:

```
class Table
{
  public $pk;
  ...
}

$Table=new Table();

$Table->pk='username'; //here I set what is PK column in my table

$Table->$pk='sbrbot'; //here I dynamically define variable and set $Table->username='sbrbot'
```

The question is when I want to retrieve this value from class I must to it in two steps;

```
class Table
{
  ...
  $pk=$this->pk;
  $value=$this->$pk;
}
```

why this:

```
$value=${$this->pk}
```

does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP requires an implicit `$this->`, whereas in Java it would be fine to access a class property with its variable name.

This means, `${$this->pk}` would be equal to `$username` which still requires `$this->`, you should use: `$this->{$this->pk}` to achieve what you what.

I would highly recommend however, changing your class structure so you don't need to have dynamic (public) variables at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Dave, you're right, $this->{$this->pk} works fine, I tried all combinations but not this one!

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
$value = $this->{$this->pk};
```

You can't access class properties using normal variable syntax, it always has to be with `->` or `::` (depending on whether they're per-object or static properties).

Comment: Thanks Barmar, this is correct but @Dave was first.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it should be this. You did not have the member $username in your Table class. And there is a bug in your assignement to $Table.

```
class Table
{
public $username;
...
}

$Table=new Table();

$pk='username'; //here I set what is PK column in my table

$Table->$pk='sbrbot'; //here I dynamically define variable and set $Table->username='sbrbot'
```

second question:

```
 $value=${$this->pk}
```

This does not work, because you did assign it to $this->username.